# Wiener measure and stochastic integrals

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I'm looking for a proof/calculation for the following result I've seen quoted a few times in papers and notes but never explained.

Let $\mu$ denote the Weiner measure on the space of real valued continuous paths $C[0,1]$. Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous deterministic function and consider the Ito integral

$$X_t = \int_0^t f(s)\mathrm{d}W_s$$

We can say that $X_t$ is a functional on the space of paths, i.e. $X_t = F(\omega)$, because you give it a (random) continuous function and it will return a number. I'm hesitant to interpet the Ito integral pathwise but I have seen things written such as $X_t(\omega) = \int_0^t f(s)\mathrm{d}\omega_s$ whatever this means, regardless one can consider expressions such as:

$$\mathbb{E}_\mu[X_t] = \int_{C[0,1]}X_t(\omega)\mu( \mathrm{d} \omega)$$

I believe that it so happens that $\mathbb{E}_\mu[X_t] = 0$ analogous (possibly equivalent) to the fact that the Ito integral is a martingale with expectation $0$. I can't recall but pretty sure I've also seen something like $\mathbb{E}_\mu[X_t^2] = \int_0^t f(s)^2ds$, the Ito isometry.

Is this correct? And if so how can I show this? The only explicit calculations I've ever seen for integrals involving $\mu$ is when we have the case that $F(\omega) = g(\omega(t_1), \ldots, \omega(t_n))$ for some times $t_i$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, all other functions have to be treated as an abstract limit of approximations of the type $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know from countless textbooks introducing Ito calculus that for continuous and deterministic, hence bounded, $f$ on $[0,t]\,:$
$$
X_t=\lim_{||\Pi||\to0}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(t_j)(W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_j})\,\quad\text{ in }L^2(\Omega,\cal A,\mathbb P)\,.
$$
Therefore, there is a subsequence that converges to $X_t$ $\quad\mathbb P$-a.s.

- This shows that the Ito integral can be interpreted "almost pathwise".

The rest of OP is correct. Use the martingale property and the well-known Ito isometry.

Book: Karatzas & Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* or many others.

Comment: I had a look at Karatzas & Shreve for the identity in my question, although it discussed the Wiener measure it didn't talk about taking expectations with respect to it. Do you have a reference? Note that I am explicitly asking about $\mathbb{E}_\mu \int_0^t f(s)\mathrm{d}W_s$ not just the fact that $\mathbb{E} \int_0^t f(s)\mathrm{d}W_s = 0$ that everyone learns in a first course.

Comment: It looks like your $\mathbb{E}_\mu \int_0^t f(s)\mathrm{d}W_s=\mathbb{E}_\mu[X_t] = \int_{C[0,1]}X_t(\omega)\mu( \mathrm{d} \omega)$  is the integral of $X_t(\omega)$ w.r.t. the Wiener measure $\mu$. If so it is *the same* as $\mathbb{E}\int_0^t f(s)\mathrm{d}W_s\,.$

Comment: OK, this makes sense. Is there an explanation for why this is or is it extremely obvious? I feel like this is something a lot of books brush under the rug and I'd like to understand this more deeply and not just prove that something equals zero.

Comment: For example, at a given time $t$ $X_t$ is now just an ordinary random variable. I was under the impression that $\mathbb{E}$ was the expectation with respect to the probability measure on some sample space $\Omega$ which is different to the Wiener measure on the space of continuous paths.

Comment: It becomes very obvious in the special case of $f\equiv 1$ where $X_t(\omega)=W_t(\omega)=\omega(t)$ and where $t\mapsto \omega(t)$ is the coordinate map on $C[0,1]\,.$ These things appear in the chapters where the Wiener measure is constructed on the concrete space $\Omega=C[0,1]\,.$

Comment: I see it this way: On an abstract space $(\Omega,\cal A,\mathbb P)$ which is large enough to admit a Brownian motion $W_t$ we know from its martingale property that $\mathbb E[X_t]$ must be zero. The concrete space $C[0,1]$ is just one example of an $\Omega$ for which it was shown that there exists a measure $\mu$ that makes $\omega(t)$ a Brownian motion. Now take the martingale property again. What holds in the general case must hold in the special case. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So we never really use the probability measure that can be defined on the filtration, at least in the context of proving the martingale property and Ito Isometry? It's really just the Weiner measure or abstract analogues that we compute these with?

Comment: The Wiener measure $\mu$ is important in the sense that it shows that BM exists. Otherwise the whole theory would be abstract nonsense. Under the buzzword Malliavin calculus a very rich theory was developed on $(C[0,1],\mu)$ itself all the way to geometric notions. You should google this if you want to dive into it.